# Google Chrome Display Issues

Tags: google-chrome

I've seen the noisy display a couple of times, and the screenshots are shown below:

Noisy display in Google Chrome

[image: Noisy display in Google Chrome]

Noisy independent of websites

[image: Noisy independent of websites]

The strange thing is the noise will sometimes suddenly disappear. And it's independent of the websites I browse. My system is macOS Catalina on 16-inch Macbook Pro. Does anyone know what happens to me?

Comment: Check extensions you've installed recently.

Comment: Try this: https://macreports.com/google-chrome-showing-blue-horizontal-lines-fix/